# Cannot use a variable in where clause

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, pnp-powershell

I am using the PnP SharePoint powershell moudle and trying to filter a users list based on a variable.

Currently here is what I have:

```
$RootFolder = '/Path/To/Folder'

$folders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $RootFolder

foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $user = Get-PnPUser | Where Title -Like "*$folder.Name*"}
}
```

This does not return results. However, if i change `| Where Title -Like "*username*"` it works fine.

The user name format is "FirstName LastName (FLastName)" and i am trying to filter based on "FLastName".

I tried single quotes and also created a variable `$username = "*" +$folder.Name+ "*"` and used that variable instead but no difference.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Where Title -Like "*$( $folder.Name )*"
```

The variable expansion/replacement ends with the "." in a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to use Mike Smith's solution.

I was able to get this to work by doing the following adjustment (adding string to the variable)

```
$RootFolder = '/Path/To/Folder'

$folders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $RootFolder

foreach ($folder in $folders){
    $user = Get-PnPUser | Where Title -Like "*$($folder.Name)*"}
}
```